# HTML table rows hover only works on even rows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a CSS hover effect on every row of an HTML table - very basic, and I've read other threads about various ways to do this.

I've implemented this many times before, but suddenly, with a new table design, I'm running into an issue. The hover style is only applied on `even` rows, and I cannot figure out why the `odd` rows aren't getting the hover style as well. See below for working code. I included every CSS style I tried, but of course, only tried one at a time.

```css
/* ==================================================
Table styling
================================================== */

.table {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  overflow: clip;
}

th {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

.table-th,
.table td {
  padding: 8px;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table>thead>tr {
  background-color: #fbbf77;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fce8c3;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.table__small {
  width: fit-content;
}

.table__wide {
  width: 100%;
}

.right-align {
  text-align: right;
}

.center-align {
  text-align: center;
}

.left-align {
  text-align: left;
}


/* ==================================================
Hover styling
// Including every hover style I tried here, but the 
// styling only works on even rows 
================================================== */

#project-deep-dive-table tbody tr:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

#project-deep-dive-table-body tr:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

tr:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

#project-deep-dive-table-body tr:nth-child(even):hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

#project-deep-dive-table-body tr:nth-child(odd):hover {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="project-deep-dive-table-container" style="display: block;">
  <table id="project-deep-dive-table" class="table">
    <thead class="sticky table-header">
      <tr>
        <!-- assessments -->
        <th class="sticky left-align table-th">Assessments</th>
        <!-- risk -->
        <th class="sticky right-align table-th">Risk</th>
        <!-- counts -->
        <th class="sticky center-align table-th">Counts</th>
        <!-- collection date -->
        <th class="sticky center-align table-th">Collection Date</th>
        <!-- posts -->
        <th class="sticky right-align table-th">Posts</th>
        <!-- completed -->
        <th class="sticky right-align table-th">Completed</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="project-deep-dive-table-body">
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">Colt Spence</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">44%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">02/04/2024 to 02/10/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">26</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/10/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">adversusjudaeos</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">90%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">02/04/2024 to 02/06/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">100</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">AwakenedOutlaw</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">90%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">02/05/2024 to 02/06/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">100</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">BigMad</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">73%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">01/31/2024 to 02/06/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">33</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">Clowns</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">90%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">02/01/2024 to 02/06/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">116</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">Derek</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">90%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">01/31/2024 to 02/06/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">59</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">Gun Digest</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">56%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">01/31/2024 to 02/06/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">15</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">Guy Jones</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">90%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">02/06/2024 to 02/06/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">100</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">Iam</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">56%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">02/04/2024 to 02/06/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">100</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">Jordi Massive</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">90%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">01/31/2024 to 02/06/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">77</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">Trolls Gays</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">53%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">02/01/2024 to 02/03/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">100</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align projects-deeper-dive">VictorNakba</td>
        <td class="right-align bold">58%</td>
        <td>
          <div class="counts-div">
            <div class="circle green">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle yellow">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle red">
              <div class="circle-text">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center-align">02/05/2024 to 02/06/2024</td>
        <td class="right-align">100</td>
        <td class="right-align">02/08/2024</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css your odd row css has the word `!important` which means it won't change the color no matter what other css you put. Just take it off and it works fine.

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Wow -- will keep this in mind moving forward when using !important flags. Thank you so much.